# How do I run Plack::Runner in the background?

Tags: perl, plack

I am trying to run a server with [`Plack::Runner`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Runner). How do I run it in the background? I've tried the following:

```
my $runner = Plack::Runner->new;
$runner->parse_options(qw' --host 127.0.0.1 --port 90210 -D');
$runner->run($app);
```

It seems to ignore the -D. I've also tried '--daemon' and that doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [plackup](https://metacpan.org/pod/plackup) or other [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) servers?

Comment: The example I found online used Plack::Runner. It's been quite a while since I've used perl in production so if there's another solution then let me know.

Comment: Usually you would just call `plackup --host 127.0.0.1 --port 90210 -D /path/to/app.psgi`. For example `.psgi` files look at the [webpage for the Plack distribution](https://metacpan.org/release/Plack) there are almost 20 examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is $app?.

```
my $runner = Plack::Runner->new;
$runner->parse_options(qw' --host 127.0.0.1 --port 90210 -D');
$runner->run("app.pm"); or "$app"
```

app.pm is app file or you can try:

```
my $app = sub {
    return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ], [ 'Hello World' ] ];
};
```

This works.